# Difference between getFeed and getFeedElement, ConnectApi

Tags: apex, chatter

I am trying to write a test class to test if a chatter post was actually posted. This is the code to test:

```
VantageConnectorTestMessage__c vctm = VantageConnectorTestMessage__c.getValues('TestMessage1');

String mess = vctm.Message__c;

ConnectApi.FeedElement feedElement = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.postFeedElement(Network.getNetworkId(), UserInfo.getUserId(), ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem, mess);
```

I was trying to get the feed element and test if it was not null:

```
ConectApi.FeedElementPage = ConnectApi.ChatterFeeds.getFeedElementsFromFeed(Network.getNetworkID(),ConnectApi.FeedElementType.FeedItem);
```

But then I read some more [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods.htm#apex_ConnectAPI_ChatterFeeds_static_methods) and I cant tell the difference between getFeed and getFeedElement..

> > getFeed(communityId, feedType, subjectId)
>
> Returns the feed for the specified feed type for the specified user.
>
> > getFeedElement(communityId, feedElementId)
>
> Returns information about the specified feed element.

does anyone know which one I want here ?

Comment: IIRC you can't really test that the ConnectAPI inserts any records because it uses callouts.

Comment: Could you please elaborate

Comment: If that's true cant I use a dummy rest response, as seen in trailhead, that is  somehow adapted to chatter in order to test that posting works.